# How to omit last character from the each word in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-2.0

So I have this paragraph.

> Hello how are you doing? how are wew

And I would like to omit all the last "w" character from this paragraph? How do I do this with ruby. I have tried

```
puts(#{string}).chomp("w")
```

And I tried the `.delete` method too.. but it simply deleted all the "w" character from all the word which I don't want it to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand the question.  You want to omit the letters without deleting them?  If your goal is to print out the string without the w, you can do that in lots of ways, but your `puts(string.chomp('w'))` would seem to do the right thing; it outputs "Hello how are you doing? how are we", with the final `w` omitted.  You'll note that if you then do `puts string`, you'll see the `w` is still there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yes I want to delete all the last "w" character from this string.For example, i want to get rid or delete last "w" from "wew" but not first "w".But at the same time I also want to delete "w" character from "how" too.

Comment: Do you want to delete every character "w" that is the last character of a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to get rid or delete last "w" from "wew" but not first "w".But
>   at the same time I also want to delete "w" character from "how" too.

```
str = "Hello how are you doing? how are wew"
str.gsub!(/w\b/, "")
puts str

--output:--
Hello ho are you doing? ho are we
```

`\b` in a regex means "word boundary", which just means look for a non "word character".  Word characters are [A-Za-z0-9_].  So the regex `w\b` looks for a 'w' followed by something that is not [A-Za-z0-9_].  The tricky thing about `\b` is that it can also match the sliver of nothingness at the beginning or end of a string:

```
"abcw"
     ^
     |
```

That string contains a 'w' followed by a word boundary.  And this string:

```
"wabc"
^
|
```

...starts with a word boundary, and then a 'w'.

Finally, `\b` doesn't actually match anything--it just ensures that there is a word boundary present, so the regex `w\b` will only ever match just 'w'.

Comment: Good answer. It handles punctuation as well (`"Ow! I got a cut, but don't know how." =? "O! I got a cut, but don't kno ho."`)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Yes about the punctuation: see last answer here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=873885

Answer (score 0):

```
word.split(' ').map(&:chop)
```